# How would you keep track of posts shared on facebook in a php app?

Tags: php, facebook

Assume you have a php CMS, and that each content it generates might be shared / liked.

The CMS dabtabase should be aware about the number of shares that a content receives. I can see two ways:

1. Schedule a batch on the CMS that query the graph api for share count, then store the result locally
2. Use the subscription api to get notified, then store the result locally

About #1: is it possible to exceed the rate limit and get blacklisted?

About #2: does the subscription api support this kind of feature (i.e. "notify me whenever a post is shared on my page")?

Can you point recommended ways of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

> About #1: is it possible to exceed the rate limit and get blacklisted?

Of course it is possible that you run into the rate limit. But you won’t get “blacklisted” forever – your API requests will just be rejected with an error message for a while, and then things will turn back to normal.

Depending on the number of URLs you need that data for, and how frequently you want to update your cache, it might be possible to achieve without running into the rate limit – or it might not. Depends on the specifics really.

> About #2: does the subscription api support this kind of feature (i.e. "notify me whenever a post is shared on my page")?

You can get notified for new posts to your FB page via webhooks – but that won’t help you of course for content shared elsewhere, and not on your specific page.

---

Maybe you want to look into Domain Insights as well. While not directly counting shares, it can still give you a lot of valuable data about how the content from your domain is performing, in regards to user interaction such as clicks, etc. https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/domain-insights